# Can you directly alter the value of a non-list argument passed to a function?

Tags: python, function

This snippet of python code

```
def changeValue(x):                                                                          
     x = 2*x                                                                                  
                                                                                              
 a = [1]                                                                                      
                                                                                              
 changeValue(a[0])                                                                            
                                                                                              
 print(a[0])
```

Will print the result "1" when I would like it to print the result "2". Can this be done by only altering the function and no other part of the code? I know there are solutions like

```
def changeValue(x):
    x[0] = 2*x[0]

a = [1]

changeValue(a)
```

or

```
def changeValue(x):
    return 2*x

a = [1]

a[0] = changeValue(a[0])
```

I am wondering if the argument passed as-is can be treated as a pointer in some sense.

[edit] - Just found a relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) so this is likely a duplicate that can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. If you pass `a[0]`, it's an `int` and it can't be mutated in any way.

If the `int` was directly in the global namespace, you could use `global` keyword. But it's not. So again no.